# Windows 7 or Windows 10 as Virtual Machine guest for best performance?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, windows-10, hyper-v

I'm planning on creating few virtual machines. Each machine is hosted locally on programmers work station in Hyper-V.

**I would like to know which operating system (Windows 7 or Windows 10) will have better performance as a guest operating system in Hyper-V.**

Why are you marking this as "Opinion" question? I'm asking for performance of OS as Hyper-V guest. There is nothing opinion based. I'm asking for numbers.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking with a sample workload? Is the 'other stuff' you mention relevant to performance?

Comment: @bertieb I thought that someone has already done such research and I didn't want to waste my time. But it looks like I'll have to do my won research. It will take some time.

Comment: Performance will depend on what you're trying to perform.  Without more specifics, there's no "right" answer, other than volumes of discussion covering all possibilities, or speculation, or reports by various people each with differing experiences.  That's the reason for the close votes.  The problem is that if you were to get very specific, the situation would apply only to you and answers wouldn't be of use to very many others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this is a general question, I believe it can be answered generally. A properly configured virtual machine, one with appropriate resources, should operate as efficiently as a host machine. With that said, the question is really which OS performs better.

[This study](http://www.techspot.com/review/1042-windows-10-vs-windows-8-vs-windows-7.html/) does an excellent job of breaking performance down into the following categories:

- Boot, Sleep, and Hibernation speeds
- Benchmark Computing (i.e. relative performance benchmarking)
- Storage (i.e. read/write speeds)
- Applications (e.g. browsers, Adobe, compression utilities)
- Encoding (i.e. object conversion rate and efficacy)
- Gaming
- Overall

The general conclusion is that Windows 10 will perform, for most purposes, without showing noticeable differences from Windows 7.  The performance margins in most cases are negligible to the end-user (milliseconds). Please note that you do have to properly allocate resources to the VM for optimal performance.